# Specify number of posts for sub-category page

Tags: functions

I have used this function to change the number of posts per page on a category page, but I can't get it to work for a **sub**-category page.

I'm trying to show 6 posts on the sub-category page and 12 on the parent category page.

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){

    if(cat_is_ancestor_of( 7, get_query_var( 'cat' ) )  ){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 6);
    }
      if(is_category( '7' )){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 12);
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
```

When I use cat_is_ancestor_of on the archive page to change the layout of the sub-category page, it works, but when I use it in that function it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, how about this then? **(Changed from first try - now tested.)**

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        if ( is_category( 7 ) ) {

            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );

        }

        //works with pretty permalinks
        $cat_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;

        if ( cat_is_ancestor_of( 7, $cat_id ) ) {

            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 );

        }

    }

}
```

Note: Still not sure about the purpose or effect of including `return ;`'s. Had no obvious effect on functionality, so have left them out.

Answer (score 0):

There is one obvious difference between your code and [the similar code in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Changing_the_number_of_posts_per_page.2C_by_post_type) - the use of a "return;" after each "set." So conforming your code to the example would look like this:

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {

   if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
       if( cat_is_ancestor_of( 7, get_query_var( 'cat' ) ) ) {
          //drumroll
          $query->set('posts_per_page', 6);
          //ta-da!
          return;
       }

       if( is_category( 7 ) ) {
          $query->set('posts_per_page', 12);
          //encore!
          return;
       }
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
```

Not tested. I wish I could authoritatively explain to you what "return;" does here. Before engaging on a research adventure, I'd be interested in knowing whether it solves the problem for you.

Comment: I tried it with the Codex code but still can't change the number of posts on the subcategory page. I'm realizing that I read the conditional explanation incorrectly though. It's targeting the parent category not the subcategory. I can't find how to target the subcategories.

Codex says: is_category( 5 ) || cat_is_ancestor_of( 5, get_query_var( 'cat' ) ) 
Returns true when the category of posts being displayed is either term_id 5, or an ancestor of term_id 5 (subcategory, sub-subcategory...).

Comment: Well... that still leaves open the question about the function (if any) of the `return;`, Will look into this in more detail shortly if you or someone else hasn't figured it out first.